# sum the data from txt file then ouput it on a single line

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, aix

(cat Type.txt &&  cat Test.txt && cat Owner.txt) > test.txt

that is my code  it is alway out like

ddddddddddddd

aaaaaaaaaaaaa

sssssssssssss

but i want  the output in txt file like this

dddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssss

i'm stuck on this  :3

Comment: So, join the files without a newline, or remove all newlines after joining?

Comment: yes without new line :D  like connect the data to each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `paste` instead:

```
paste -d "" Type.txt Test.txt Owner.txt
```

Results:

```
dddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssss
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is

```
echo `cat Type.txt Test.txt Owner.txt` > test.txt
```

or, equivalently,

```
echo $(cat Type.txt Test.txt Owner.txt) > test.txt
```

A couple of drawbacks:

1. They will output `ddddddddddddd aaaaaaaaaaaaa sssssssssssss` (with spaces between the files –– or, to be more precise, with spaces between the lines in the files).
2. *Your* command line will stop dead in its tracks if `cat Type.txt` fails, because you are connecting the `cat` commands with `&&`.  Since these `echo` commands invoke only a single `cat` command, you will get `Test.txt` and `Owner.txt` even if `Type.txt` doesn’t exist.

If either of the above is a show-stopper, get down and dirty with

```
(tr -d "\n" < Type.txt  &&  tr -d "\n" < Test.txt  &&  cat Owner.txt) > test.txt
```